# Replace lines in file according to numeration in file

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics, python-re

I'm trying to replace the new changes in `a[i]` list, to the original `er.pdb` file
using the numbers in both the file & the items in the list.

Here's an example of how the items in the list looks like.

```
['ATOM  168  N   MET A  48       6.674   9.818  33.156  1.00 45.09           N  ',
 'ATOM  169  CA  MET A  48       6.049  10.959  32.490  1.00 44.83           C  ',
 'ATOM  170  C   MET A  48       4.687  10.621  31.903  1.00 44.85           C  ']
```

And here's the file `er.pdb`

```
HETATM  168  N   MSE A  48       6.674   9.818  33.156  1.00 45.09           N  
HETATM  169  CA  MSE A  48       6.049  10.959  32.490  1.00 44.83           C  
HETATM  170  C   MSE A  48       4.687  10.621  31.903  1.00 44.85           C
```

So both have the same number records (`168, 169, 170` etc..)

One of the ways I can think of is to use pandas. However, is there another way to do this without pandas?
Here's my code. I used regex to replace certain patterns, like MSE to MET.

```
import re

with open('er.pdb','r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    a = re.findall('.*HETATM.*\s{2}\d{3}\s{1,2}\w{1,2}.*MSE.*', contents)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        ### HETATM to ATOM
        a[i] = re.sub(r'^\w{6}', 'ATOM', a[i])
        ### SE to SD & spacing
        a[i] = re.sub(r' SE   MSE', '  SD  MET', a[i])
        ### MSE to MET
        a[i] = re.sub(r' MSE ', ' MET ', a[i])
        ### SE to S
        a[i] = re.sub(r'  SE  ', '   S  ', a[i])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: isn't your code working now? If not, what is the output / error if you are getting any?

Comment: Whats wrong with the code you have?  Are you asking for a more elegant solution, or??

Comment: @bikalpa & @Elrond Supports Monica the script works, however `a = re.findall... ` puts all of the lines that need changing into a list, and once those items in the list are changed in a[i], I need to put them back into the file `er.pdb`

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment you have made in the question earlier, I understand that you already have made changes to the items and they are now in the list `a`.

Now to write that list to the file, you can do:

```py
text_to_write = "\n".join(a)
with open("er.pdb", "w") as target_file:
    target_file.write(text_to_write)
```

Comment: Thanks! Though I want to join the modified file using the numbers for each new line (the numbers on the 2nd column, after ATOM or HETATM column). The method you have given joined all the strings together & replaced all of the old data with the new ones. Whereas I only wanted to replace certain chunks of the old data.

Comment: which particular chunks do you want to replace?

Comment: Thanks for getting back @bikalpa I just want to replace the old chunks (e.g the chunks with HETATOM & MSE records in them for example) with the new ones (e.g. ATOM & MET), while not deleting the rest of the file that is unchanged.